# Saving file attachment to folder on search then writing its path to DB?

Tags: vb.net, email, ado.net

I would like to save the file attachment to a folder on the website.

My code that creates the attachment to email is like this:

```
' Attachments
If Not (FileUpload1.FileName = "") Then
    Dim myattachment1 As New Net.Mail.Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    message.Attachments.Add(myattachment1)
End If
```

I would like to save the attachments to "C:\DotNetNuke5\Portals\6\JobApplicationDocuments" on the server. Then I would like to save the path to the file in a DB column called 'attachment'.

I would like some help, or things I can search with Google as I am new to this. Thanks

Edit: I now have this code:

```
If Not (FileUpload1.FileName = "") Then
    Dim myattachment1 As New Net.Mail.Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    message.Attachments.Add(myattachment1)

    Dim savePath As String = "C:\DotNetNuke5\Portals\6\JobApplicationDocuments\"
    If (FileUpload1.HasFile) Then
        savePath += FileUpload1.FileName
    End If

End If
```

But I can't get it to save in the directory.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer rather than editing it into the question. Thanks!

Comment: done, please up vote my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save uploaded file, using this code:

```
        Dim savePath = "C:\DotNetNuke5\Portals\6\JobApplicationDocuments\"

        Dim uploadedFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(input.FileName)

        savePath += uploadedFileName

        Try

        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(savePath)

        Catch ex As Exception

        'error. do something

        End Try
```

Comment: I did this already but thanks for the solution. Can you suggest what sort of error handling i can use if the upload fails due to the hard disk being full? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how to check if hard disk is full or not. but easiest way is to wrap the code inside a Try Catch. updated my answer, check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ' Attachments
        If Not (FileUpload1.FileName = "") Then
            Dim myattachment1 As New Net.Mail.Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            message.Attachments.Add(myattachment1)

            'file path
            Dim savePath As String = "C:\DotNetNuke5\Portals\6\JobApplicationDocuments\"
            'check if control has file
            If (FileUpload1.HasFile) Then

                'append the applicants email address and the fileupload file name to avoid overwritting same file names.
                savePath += TxtEmail.Text + "-" + FileUpload1.FileName

                'attempted to do date time append but unsuccessfull
                'String.Format("{0}-{1: dd-M-yy}", FileUpload1.FileName, DateTime.Now)

                'save the file to its path
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath)

                'open the connection to the database
                Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=192.168.1.0\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DNN;User ID=DNNAdmin;Password=password;"
                Dim sqlConnection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

                'insert the data
                Dim queryString As String = "INSERT INTO [tblJobApplication] ([message], [email], [attachment]) VALUES (@message, @email, @attachment)"
                Dim sqlCommand As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)

                'set the parameters
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@message", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = message.Body
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtEmail.Text
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@attachment", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = savePath

                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
                sqlConnection.Open()
                Try
                    rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
                Finally
                    sqlConnection.Close()
                End Try


                ' Send the message
                Dim smtp As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
                smtp.Host = "localhost"
                smtp.Send(message)
                Response.Redirect("applicationcompleted2.htm#top")
            End If
            Return


        End If

    End If
```

Above is my solution. Thanks

I append the users email address from the form to the file attachment so it stops a user uploading cv.doc and overwritting someone elses cv.doc. It also saves the path to the database.